# What's the difference between setTime(...) and setTimestamp(...) in Hibernate Query?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I wonder why the setTime method behaves exactly like setDate, date without time, or instead to set the time on 2014-07-01 13:21:01 it is set on 2014-07-01 00:00:00 ?!?!

Is setTime deprecated?
Should I use setTimestamp???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Databases other than Oracle actually do distinguish between three different datatypes:

- `DATE` only date, no time
- `TIME` only time of the day, no date
- `TIMESTAMP` both, date & time.

JDBC tries to abstract standard SQL concepts and the above three datatypes are defined by ANSI SQL and thus JDBC needs to support them.

As Oracle's date always includes the time, you **have** to use `setTimestamp()` otherwise the time is lost when you store it in the database.

Answer (score 1):

setTime() Method :

The java.util.Calendar.setTime(Date) method sets Calendar's time with the given Date.

Following is the declaration for java.util.Calendar.setTime() method

```
public final void setTime(Date date)
```

This method does not return a value.

Example :
The following example shows the usage of java.util.calendar.setTime() method.

```
 package com.tutorialspoint;

      import java.util.*;

      public class CalendarDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  // create a calendar
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

  // get the current time
  System.out.println("Current time is :" + cal.getTime());

  // create new date and set it
  Date date = new Date(95, 10, 10);
  cal.setTime(date);

  // print the new time
  System.out.println("After setting Time:  " + cal.getTime());
    }
 }
```

SetTimestamp Method :

Sets the designated parameter to the given timestamp and calendar values.
Syntax

```
          public void setTimestamp(java.lang.String sCol,
                     java.sql.Timestamp x,
                     java.util.Calendar c)
```

Comment: The question is not about `Calendar.setTime()` but about `PreparedStatement.setTime()` I guess